# How to dynamically build list view JQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to dynamically add a list view.
    I am able to build the list view dynamically but i am appending

to  hard     coded tag in the below html snippet.

```
The HTML code snippet.
<ul id="mymenu" data-role="listview" >
</ul>

Jquery Code Snippet.
$("#accpmenu").append('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a"  "> <img src="letterheader.png" >'+ this.textContent + '  </a> </li>');
```

I even want to dynamically build the  and  then append

Please help me in achieving this.

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: What are you dynamically building based on? If you're using a server side script to return data from a file or database, and you want to dynamically build based on the contents of that file or database, use a for() or while() loop in your server side script.

Answer (score 53):

After appending you must refresh the list:

```
  $("#mymenu").listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 18):

Here is an example which creates a list dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/SuSpv/

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I used your example to help write my own implementation, but I got an error, "cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'. My list view items contain anchor tags which invoke a javascript function. Do you think this is my problem and could you suggest a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I have use below code working fine to me

## Dynamic Listview

```
<script>


var myArray = ["Arun", "kumar", "Mani", "Vimal", "Vinoth"];

$.each(myArray, function(index, value){

    console.log("INDEX: " + index + " VALUE: " + value);


});


         var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <myArray.length; i++) {


       output.push('<li><img src="img/img_help.png">' + myArray[i] +'</li>');

    }

     $('#coursemates').append(output.join('')).listview('refresh');

     $("#coursemates").listview("refresh");

</script>
```